# How do I translate placeholder text in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I want Rails to automatically translate placeholder text like it does with form labels. How can I do this?

Form labels are translated automatically like this:

```
= f.text_field :first_name
```

This helper uses the locale file:

```
en:
  active_model:
    models:
      user:
        attributes:
          first_name: Your name
```

Which outputs this HTML

```
<label for="first_name">Your name</label>
```

How can I make it so the placeholder is translated? Do I have to type the full scope like this:

```
= f.text_field :first_name,
    placeholder: t('.first_name', scope: 'active_model.models.user.attributes.first_name')
```

Is there are easier way?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If using Rails 4.2, you can set the placeholder attribute to true:

```
= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: true
```

and specify the placeholder text in the locale file like this:

```
en:
  helpers:
    placeholder:
      user:
        first_name: "Your name"
```

Comment: It require `accepts_nested_attributes_for :model` for nested model.

Answer (score 1):

With Rails >= 4.2, you can set the placeholder attribute to true

`= f.text_field :first_name, placeholder: true`

and in your local file (e.g. en.yml):

```
ru:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        first_name: Your name
```

otherwise (Rails >= 3.0) I think you can write something like this:

```
= f.text_field :attr,
    placeholder: "#{I18n.t 'activerecord.attributes.user.first_name'}"
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can view the source on render at http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionView/Helpers/Tags/Label to see how Rails does it. It probably doesn't get a lot better than you have, but you could probably swipe some of Rail's logic and stick it in a helper, if you have a lot of them to do. Alternatively, you may consider using a custom form builder to remove some of the repetition in your whole form, not just placeholders.